# Binding actions similar to bind-attr in ember

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

Hi i am using emberJS for binding attributes to the elements can be done by using bind-attr , the same i want to do for action to user interaction.

```
  <button {{#if DS.session.canEditTrailers}} {{action "addTTU"}} {{/if}}  
  {{bind-attr class="DS.session.canEditTrailers:ttuName:readOnlyTTUName" 
  disabled="DS.session.canEditTrailers::disabled"}}>
```

Here in above i used if condition for binding action to the element button.
It is not working..Can any please tell me is there any solution similar like bind-attr for actions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do what you want in the template. You have to handle this in your action handler itself. So instead of writing `{{#if DS.session.canEditTrailers}}` in the template, you should write:

```
// Your controller (or where you handle the action):
actions: {
  addTTU: function() {
    if(DS.session.canEditTrailers) {
      // your code
    }
  }
}
```